# Bring element width in when line wraps?

Tags: html, width, css, word-wrap

This seems like it might be a dead-end question, but in the off-chance that there might be some way to do what I'm looking for, I thought I'd ask the geniuses at stackoverflow before giving up.
Any type of solution at all (Javascript, CSS, etc) would do!

What I'd like to be able to do can be seen on this page:
http://willdo.ca/test.php

I noticed that when a line wraps in an element with an auto width (ex. inline-block element), and with max-width set on it, whitespace remains causing the element to fill out to max-width even though the text doesn't technically reach this max-width (though I understand why it behaves this way, as this is technically the width of the element before the line was forced to wrap).

Hopefully the page I've supplied does a better job at describing what I've attempted to here.
      The first outlined element is the normal (proper) behavior.
      The second outlined element is the behavior I'd like to create (simulated by adding a line-break).

Here is a link to view/download the HTML I've used if need be: http://willdo.ca/test.txt

Comment: try using white-space propetry with a value of pre

Comment: No linewrap occurs with the white-space property pre

Answer (score 0):

The only reason the text wraps in the first place is because it hits the edge of the element as defined by auto (parent width)/ px / % or the max/min widths. It then pushes all other text onto the next line keeping words together (obviously).

The only conceivable way I can see of doing it would be to calculate what the width of the actual text is and size the box accordingly all in JS. This is stupendously difficult for such a problem and serious overkill. It requires calculating each character width (not all the same) and they depend on DPI of the client, font-type, browser zoom, accessibility features and a whole host of other things.

So sorry it's not looking very possible, what's the scenario? It's very big font in your example with a purpose placed long word.